# JPQL how to create new DTO using Select with collection parameter

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, dto

Im trying to project a DTO from entity, directly from DB using repository.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEW com.jm.online_store.model.dto.ProductDto(p.id, p.comments) FROM 
    Product p WHERE p.id = :id")
ProductDto getCommentProductDto(@Param("id") Long productId);
```

However I keep getting an error

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. as col_1_0_ from product product0_ inner join comment comments1_ on product0_.' at line 1

Everething works fine up until im trying to pass a Collection as a query constructor parameter.

My DTO class

```
public class ProductDto {

    private java.lang.Long id;
    private Collection<Comment> comments;

    public ProductDto(java.lang.Long id, Collection<Comment> comments) {
        this.id = id;
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public ProductDto(java.lang.Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ProductDto() {
    }

    public java.lang.Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(java.lang.Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Collection<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Collection<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated, been stuck on this for days now...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you can't pass a collection as argument in the JPQL constructor syntax.

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Product.class)
public interface ProductDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    Set<CommentDto> getComments();

    @EntityView(Comment.class)
    interface CommentDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getComment();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ProductDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ProductDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features